# React / Formatting JSON Object with line breaks

Tags: json, object, line-breaks

Is it possible to have line breaks within one value of an JSON Object?
I tried with \n with br-tag and with template literals like `bla bla ${\n} bla bla bla`, but it's not working.

My code looks like this in the Object

```
export const Data = [
{
    id: 1,
    item: 'blablabla',
    detail:
        'bla bla bla. <here I want a line break> bla bla bla'
}]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you use the prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'text <br/> text' }}` on the element where you want to render the text you can do it with `<br/>`

Comment: Thanks Nicolae.

I read about dangerouslySetInnerHTML and I'm not sure, if I should use it.
Is there any other possibility to have a line break in an external data object value?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I found is to use the css property  `white-space: "pre-wrap";` , it will let you use line breaks without `<br/>`

I would also recommend to write the text with `template literals` so you don't need to use `\n`

```
export const Data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        item: 'blablabla',
        detail: "bla bla bla. \n bla bla bla",
        betterDetail: 
            `it will
             also
             works like this
             `
     }]
```